# how to change back button on RateMyAppNoButton in flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code, rate

i'm using 
https://pub.dev/packages/rate_my_app 
but i can not change back btn fontSize or color.
how can i do so?

```
final Widget cancelButton = RateMyAppNoButton(
                _rateMyApp,
                text: 'back',

                callback: () => setState(() {}),
              );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because the class RateMyAppNoButton doesn't allow much customising.

Try using standard Flutter buttons e.g.

```
final Widget cancelButton = RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text('Cancel', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to changing colors and fonts,

```
final Widget cancelButton = RaisedButton(
    onTap: () { },
    child: Text('back', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14), color: Colors.red),
);
```

Comment: And how is this answer any different from the one above ?